# if statement with $_GET disappears after run

Tags: php

When Edit comment is pressed it sends ?edit=true to the same page. It then runs the second if statement chaning the >Edit comment< into >Save comment<. But when pressed >Save comment< it wont change back to >Edit comment<.. 


How can I make it change back into >edit comment< ?

The same goes for the contenteditable attribute being set to true or false. It only changes to true but won't change back to false.


Also I had no idea what to set as title so feel free to edit it lol.

## kritiek.php

```
function is_logged_in(){
    if($_SESSION["admin_logged_in"]){
        return true;
    } else {
  return false;
}

<?php if (is_logged_in()) {
    if ($_GET['edit'] === 'edit_false' || $_GET['edit'] == "") {
        echo "<a href='kritiek.php?edit=edit_true'>Edit comment</a>";
    }
    if ($_GET['edit'] === 'edit_true') {
         echo "<a href='kritiek.php?edit=edit_false'>Save comment</a>";
    }
} ?>




<p <?php if($_GET['edit'] === 'edit_true'){ edit_comment(true);}
    if($_GET['edit'] === 'edit_false'){ edit_comment(false); }?>
        ><?php echo $row['comments']; ?></p>

function edit_comment($link) {
    if (is_logged_in()) {
        if($link === true) {
            echo "contenteditable='true'";
        } else {
            echo "contenteditable='false'";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT: changed

```
 $_GET['edit'] == true
```

to

```
 $_GET['edit'] === 'edit_true'
```

disappearing the button completely.

EDIT: fixed that by changing

```
if ($_GET['edit'] === 'edit_false'
```

to

```
if ($_GET['edit'] === 'edit_false' || $_GET['edit'] == "")
```

Comment: You are comparing to the boolean true, which in both cases is true (see [this demo](http://3v4l.org/3fN14)). Use a string comparison like `$_GET['edit'] === 'true'` instead

Comment: exactly ^ true and false have special meaning in PHP and are reserved keywords/constants

Comment: First of all `$_GET['edit']` will always be a string, so `'true' == true` and `'false' == true`. So all of your logic is flawed. You can use [filter_var](http://php.net/filter-var) or [filter_input](http://php.net/filter-input) instead to filter this variable down to a boolean. For example, `if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'edit', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) == false)`

Comment: I prefer checking for the key it self, false being the lack of it in the $_GET array, true being any value other then it missing, : ), then its a simple isset() check, typically I would use the id of what is being edited as the value there, but that is just me.

Comment: Why are you overthinking such a trivial problem? Why not just use `filter_input` like suggested? That clearly addresses your needs in full, which you are struggling to address at every turn by deliberately choosing to take the inferior solution when a superior one is just as readily available to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're checking for a Boolean false not the string 'false' so ..

```
if ($_GET['edit'] == false) {
```

to

```
if ($_GET['edit'] === 'false') {
```

obviously change the other checks also

Comment: Why not do a typesafe comparison aka `===`?

Comment: @kingkero bad habbits.

Comment: both plus the fact you changed the answer

Comment: ah that makes perfect sense, however the button is now gone. Renaming the ?edit=false to ?edit=edit_false doesnt work either. Am I missing something?

Comment: @shadryck can you update the question with the current code pls.

Comment: got to change all the vars to match `..kritiek.php?edit=false.`. >> `..kritiek.php?edit=edit_false ..`

Comment: @Dagon haha my bad, just noticed. Forgot to update it here. The button is still gone however

Answer (score 1):

The better way to compare user input from the outside is to use [filter_input](http://php.net/filter-input), since all input is ultimately parsed as a string in PHP. You can't compare boolean values like that directly to a string (i.e. `'false' != false`).

Instead, you could try something like this...

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'edit', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) == false) {
    /* $_GET['edit'] is false */
} elseif (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'edit', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) == true) {
    /* $_GET['edit'] is true */
}
```

This makes the comparison safer, since `filter_input()` will parse a string of `"1"`, `"true"`, `"on"`, and "`yes"` as a boolean `true` and will parse a string of `"0"`, `"false"`, `"off"`, `"no"`, and `""` - an empty string - as a boolean `false`. Additionally, if `$_GET['edit']` is not set or `null`, `filter_input()` will still return null, still making it falsey, which is still much more expected and obvious behavior than trying to compare strings to booleans.

Answer (score 0):

My prefered way of doing it is using the id of the item being edited.  The lack of the `edit` key being false than it's a simple

```
isset( $_GET['edit'] )
```

style check that avoids all that type based stuff.  And what are you editing, why this id

```
url?edit=1
```

Edit id #1 or what have you.